# MariaDB ERROR: class /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/JavaWrappers.jar not found

Tags: database, mariadb, database-migration

I am using MariaDB 10.11 with connect engine to migrate from one mairadb to another mariadb.

Prior to executing the commands JavaWrapper.jar and mariadb java connector 8 are dependencies required to execute the migration. So I downloaded the JavaWrapper.jar file provided from [MariaDB's Jira story](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10936) and placed it in `/usr/lib/mysql/plugin`. In the screenshot below I have the 2 files needed to perform the migration using mariadb connect (JavaWrappers.Jar and mariadb-java-client-3.1.3.jar).
[image]

Onced set I then create a table to reference the remote database. I then execute the command to set the JVM class path to opendjk 8 and other necessary commands to execute the migration:

```sql
MariaDB [test]> create table sample_server1 ( bloodType varchar(100) not null) engine=CONNECT table_type=JDBC connection='jdbc:mariadb://10.50.6.101:3306/test?user=root&password=r00t';
MariaDB [test]> create table sample like sample_server1;
MariaDB [test]> set global connect_jvm_path="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server";
MariaDB [test]> alter table sample engine=InnoDB;
ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 174 'ERROR: class /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/JavaWrappers.jar not found!' from CONNECT
```

I am unsure why I get the /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/JavaWrappers.jar not found! error when the jar is located in the correct place iwth proper read permissions. Can someone suggest why this is happening? is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the bug report ([MDEV-31015](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-31015)).

The [connect_class_path](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-system-variables/#connect_class_path) needs to include the `JavaWrappers.jar` file.

MariaDB needs to sort out its packaging of it ([MDEV-26218](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26218)).